# Pulling Data by Using "Combo Box (Form Control)"

Tags: excel, combobox, excel-2013

I wanna pull some data by using "Combo Box (Form Control)". But I can't manage it. Here are the some images about my problem.

[image]

Second image:
[image]

Here is my excel file: [**download xlsx**](http://zinzinzibidi.com/download/dropdownlistissue.xlsx)

Comment: You need to read about [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and for example `=VLOOKUP(A3,L3:N12,2,FALSE)` in B4

Comment: Hi, check my answer. I solved the problem by using =INDEX(). You can download the solved xlsx file also.

Comment: There are many possible solutions to your problem, but the way you chose will work only if L column contains consecutive integers starting with 1.

Comment: No. INDEX() is better than VLOOKUP(). I was using it 3 years ago. I just didn't remember it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem thanks to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXlKM3YaWag).

Solution is INDEX() function.

```
For A cell: =INDEX(G3:G12;A3;1)

For B cell: =INDEX(H3:H12;A3;1)
```

Here is my updated excel file: [download xlsx](http://zinzinzibidi.com/download/dropdownlistissue-solved.xlsx) (Note: I made hide A column.)
You can check the formulas.